# Optimizing Gurobi model (PuLP) for a symmetric MIP with binary variables

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, gurobi, pulp

*In short; Is it possible to solve this faster?*

Apparently, the author of the original linked solution used SAS to solve the problem in under an hour. For me, it took me 3 and a half hours on my laptop using GUROBI academic license.

---

I'm trying to get into integer linear programming. For my first project, I want to replicate the results from the solution to the "[8 soldiers lining up for the morning assembly](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/106047/32666) " problem. In short, it boils down to:

> Let P be the set of all permutations on 8 symbols. Let binary decision variable xₐ indicate whether permutation a∈P appears in the solution. For each of the 8⋅7⋅6=336 triples t∈T, let Pₜ⊂P be the subset of permutations that contain that triple. The problem is to maximize:
>
> The (sum of xₐ across all a∈P), subject to (sum of all xₐ across all a∈Pₜ) <= 1 for every t∈T.

I define the permutations in a generalized code (for N symbols and M-lets, then N=8 and M=3 for triplets.)

```
from sympy.utilities.iterables import permutations
from sympy import factorial

N, M = 8, 3
P = ''.join([str(_) for _ in range(N)])
T = {''.join(p):set() for p in permutations(P,M)}
I, J = {}, {}
for i, p in enumerate(permutations(P)):
    permutation = ''.join(p)
    I[permutation], J[i] = i, permutation
    for j in range(N-M+1):
        T[permutation[j:j+M]].add(permutation)
upper_bound = len(T)//(N-M+1)
print(f"Total of {N}!={factorial(N)} permutations and {len(T)} {M}-subpermutations are ready.")
print(f"Upper bound: {upper_bound}.")
```

And then use this to define the model (with an 8 hour time limit)

```
from pulp import LpMaximize, LpProblem, LpStatus, lpSum, LpVariable, GUROBI

x = {i: LpVariable(name=f"x{i}", cat="Binary") for i in range(factorial(N))}  
model = LpProblem(name=f"{N}_soldiers_{M}_puzzle", sense=LpMaximize)
for i,t in enumerate(T.keys()):
    model += (lpSum([x[I[p]] for p in T[t]]) <= 1, f"constrain{i}")
model += (x[0] == 1,"WLOG")
objective = lpSum([x[i] for i in range(factorial(N))]) 
model += (objective <= upper_bound,"upper_bound")
model += objective

print("\nStarting GUROBI solver...")
status = model.solve(solver=GUROBI(msg=True,timeLimit=60*60*8,LogToConsole=0))
```

Things to notice:

- Due to symmetry, I added `model += (x[0] == 1,"WLOG")`. But, I do not know how to exploit symmetry further.
- I added the `"upper_bound"` condition, but It appears it doesn't make a difference either way.

Apparently, the author of the original linked solution used SAS to solve the problem in under an hour.

For me, using this GUROBI model on my laptop is taking hours and more. Can we optimize it to be faster? Or is there some other solver that PuLP can use that would work better on this model? *(I switched to an academic gurobi license after GLPK did not manage to solve it over night.)*

My latest log file (had to cut it short for character limit):

```
Gurobi Optimizer version 9.1.1 build v9.1.1rc0 (win64)
Thread count: 4 physical cores, 4 logical processors, using up to 4 threads
Optimize a model with 338 rows, 40320 columns and 282241 nonzeros
Model fingerprint: 0xa0617a52
Variable types: 0 continuous, 40320 integer (0 binary)
Coefficient statistics:
  Matrix range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  Objective range  [1e+00, 1e+00]
  Bounds range     [1e+00, 1e+00]
  RHS range        [1e+00, 6e+01]
Found heuristic solution: objective 43.0000000
Presolve removed 7 rows and 3624 columns
Presolve time: 0.88s
Presolved: 331 rows, 36696 columns, 256872 nonzeros
Variable types: 0 continuous, 36696 integer (36696 binary)

Starting sifting (using dual simplex for sub-problems)...

    Iter     Pivots    Primal Obj      Dual Obj        Time
       0          0     infinity     -4.7000000e+02      1s
       1        306   1.9619997e+09  -1.8714284e+02      1s
       2       1956  -3.2453701e+01  -9.5576700e+01      1s
       3       4263  -3.7141380e+01  -6.0449129e+01      2s
       4       6546  -5.3519665e+01  -5.9851524e+01      2s
       5       8510  -5.5832220e+01  -5.8952552e+01      3s

Sifting complete


Root relaxation: objective 5.600000e+01, 10313 iterations, 1.97 seconds
Total elapsed time = 17.14s
Total elapsed time = 24.25s
Total elapsed time = 48.86s
Total elapsed time = 53.33s

    Nodes    |    Current Node    |     Objective Bounds      |     Work
 Expl Unexpl |  Obj  Depth IntInf | Incumbent    BestBd   Gap | It/Node Time

     0     0   56.00000    0  165   43.00000   56.00000  30.2%     -   59s
H    0     0                      52.0000000   56.00000  7.69%     -   61s
H    0     0                      54.0000000   56.00000  3.70%     -  100s
     0     0   56.00000    0  298   54.00000   56.00000  3.70%     -  102s
     0     0   56.00000    0  140   54.00000   56.00000  3.70%     -  214s
H    0     0                      55.0000000   56.00000  1.82%     -  246s
     0     0   56.00000    0  161   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%     -  247s
     0     0   56.00000    0  228   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%     -  250s
     0     0   56.00000    0  212   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%     -  277s
     0     0   56.00000    0  285   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%     -  329s
     0     0   56.00000    0  257   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%     -  345s
     0     0   56.00000    0  257   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%     -  348s
     0     2   56.00000    0  253   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%     -  364s
     2     3   56.00000    1  257   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  8759  387s
     4     4   56.00000    1  147   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  4380  575s
     5     5   56.00000    1  134   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  3504  743s
     6     6   56.00000    1  144   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  2920  781s
     7     6   56.00000    1  254   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  2503  819s
     8     7   56.00000    1  290   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  2190  841s
     9     8   56.00000    1  280   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  1946  875s
    10     8   56.00000    1  294   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  1752  891s
    11     9   56.00000    1  294   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  1593  899s
    12    10   56.00000    1  284   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  1460  915s
    13    10   56.00000    1  317   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  1348  924s
    14    11   56.00000    1  314   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  1251  950s
    15    12   56.00000    1  320   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  1168  958s
    16    12   56.00000    1  331   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  1095  998s
    17    13   56.00000    1  320   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  1030 1024s
    18    14   56.00000    1  320   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   973 1093s
    19    17   56.00000   14  333   55.00000   56.00000  1.82% 16480 1161s
    21    21   56.00000   15  333   55.00000   56.00000  1.82% 14954 1234s
    25    23   56.00000   16  332   55.00000   56.00000  1.82% 12618 1286s
    29    26   56.00000   16  324   55.00000   56.00000  1.82% 10952 1346s
    33    29   56.00000   17  333   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  9669 1372s
    37    31   56.00000   17  328   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  8648 1405s
    41    34   56.00000   18  333   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  7821 1428s
    45    37   56.00000   18  327   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  7150 1579s
    49    42   56.00000   19  333   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  6576 1611s
    56    47   56.00000   20  333   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  5778 1642s
    63    78   56.00000   21  334   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  5160 1733s
    95   221   56.00000   23  334   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  3480 1900s
   250   303   56.00000   27  321   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%  1421 2081s
  1258   322   56.00000   55  121   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   602 2118s
  2173   333 infeasible   64        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   548 2144s
  2884   385   56.00000   57  131   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   532 2166s
  3596   411 infeasible   58        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   515 2189s
  3968   424   56.00000   43  234   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   507 2230s
  3981   443   56.00000   44  234   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   506 2267s
  4000   517   56.00000   48  233   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   504 2292s
  4380   518   56.00000   73  153   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   497 2378s
  4387   565   56.00000   74  153   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   496 2399s
  5294   556   56.00000   56  120   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   492 2437s
  5485   594   56.00000   57  123   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   491 2460s
  5915   712 infeasible   57        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   489 2484s
  6561   721 infeasible   68        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   483 2507s
  7614   756   56.00000   73  139   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   484 2528s
  8751   776   56.00000   41  184   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   484 2548s
  9929   795   56.00000   76  137   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   486 2569s
 11200   833   56.00000   75  154   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   488 2648s
 13684   840   56.00000   69  139   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   495 2663s
 14584   881   56.00000   42  178   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   496 2678s
 14725   945   56.00000   60  167   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   495 2692s
 15603   952   56.00000   84  143   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   494 2709s
 16132  1027   56.00000   62  148   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   495 2726s
 16783  1077 infeasible   92        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   494 2739s
 17705  1055   56.00000   58  128   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   494 2751s
 18547  1034 infeasible   72        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   495 2763s
 19242  1058 infeasible   81        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   495 2774s
 20032  1040 infeasible   95        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   496 2786s
 20772  1048 infeasible   77        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   497 2797s
 21530  1133   56.00000   86  152   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   498 3287s
 23023  1114   56.00000   74  134   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   498 3304s
 23838  1117   56.00000   84  134   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   499 3317s
 24509  1088 infeasible   98        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   501 3330s
 25326  1079 infeasible   78        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   502 3344s
 25999  1058   56.00000   74  135   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   503 3356s
 26666  1050 infeasible   89        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   504 3367s
 27396  1076   56.00000   76  126   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   506 3445s
 28034  1071   56.00000   81  140   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   506 3458s
 28879  1111   56.00000   77  151   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   506 3470s
 29474  1108   56.00000   71  135   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   506 3485s
 30263  1167 infeasible   93        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   507 3498s
 31138  1143 infeasible   90        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   507 3510s
 31960  1144   56.00000   74  142   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   507 3624s
 31967  1090   56.00000   75  142   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   507 3636s
 32569  1064 infeasible   63        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   508 3648s
 33337  1035 infeasible   91        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   509 3660s
 34006  1092   56.00000   67  140   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   510 3671s
 34805  1143 infeasible   72        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   509 3717s
 36468  1176 infeasible   84        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   509 3730s
 36863  1193   56.00000   71  132   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   509 3745s
 37318  1171   56.00000   75  141   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   509 3760s
 37802  1131 infeasible   76        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   509 3775s
 38288  1100 infeasible   74        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   510 3789s
 39133  1060   56.00000   61  121   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   510 3802s
 39967  1095 infeasible   83        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   511 3814s
 40728  1135   56.00000   58  154   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   511 3827s
 41362  1104   56.00000   90  128   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   511 3841s
 41973  1133   56.00000   68  146   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   512 3854s
 42664  1152   56.00000   77  151   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   512 3867s
 43363  1140 infeasible   88        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   513 3879s
 44043  1155   56.00000   81  144   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   514 3890s
 44399  1091 infeasible   79        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   514 3902s
 45077  1159   56.00000   60  151   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   515 3914s
 45801  1168 infeasible   75        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   516 3956s
 47178  1197   56.00000   71  151   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 3982s
 47467  1190 infeasible   80        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 3996s
 48262  1164   56.00000   81  132   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 4010s
 49032  1185 infeasible   88        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   519 4022s
 49785  1214   56.00000   81  151   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   520 4033s
 50534  1157 infeasible   88        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   520 4045s
 51183  1121 infeasible   83        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   521 4056s
 51835  1081 infeasible   91        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   522 4067s
 52241  1075 infeasible   89        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   522 4079s
 52801  1150 infeasible   85        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   523 4092s
 53438  1151   56.00000   60  148   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   522 4169s
 53445  1200   56.00000   61  147   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   522 4181s
 54146  1252 infeasible   89        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   521 4202s
 54758  1247   56.00000   76  125   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   521 4213s
 55573  1297   56.00000   80  139   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   520 4223s
 56237  1302 infeasible   67        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   520 4264s
 57604  1334   56.00000   65  139   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   519 4275s
 58328  1245   56.00000   70  128   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   519 4284s
 58917  1220 infeasible   96        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   519 4293s
 59566  1214 infeasible  106        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   519 4303s
 60048  1328 infeasible   79        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   519 4331s
 60576  1324 infeasible  102        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 4415s
 60588  1349   56.00000   87  134   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 4426s
 61361  1326 infeasible   88        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 4436s
 62074  1326   56.00000   59  148   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 4446s
 62640  1411 infeasible   75        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 4457s
 63277  1353 infeasible   79        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 4490s
 63713  1374   56.00000   72  142   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 4517s
 64314  1376 infeasible  100        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 4535s
 65036  1482   56.00000   72  144   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 4548s
 65766  1463 infeasible   84        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 4561s
 66389  1481 infeasible  115        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   516 4574s
 66588  1481   56.00000   77  132   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   516 4576s
 67121  1453 infeasible   88        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   516 4622s
 68467  1463 infeasible   90        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 4633s
 68891  1433 infeasible   62        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   516 4650s
 69379  1476   56.00000   63  141   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 4664s
 70167  1472 infeasible   77        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   516 4676s
 70907  1401   56.00000   79  135   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   516 4689s
 71564  1360   56.00000   96  139   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 4716s
 72197  1355 infeasible   80        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 4738s
 72826  1375   56.00000   67  140   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 4755s
 73520  1342   56.00000   79  137   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 4820s
 73812  1342 infeasible  100        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 4834s
 74252  1359   56.00000   57  143   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 4845s
 74979  1292   56.00000   60  141   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 4857s
 75656  1337 infeasible   67        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   519 4868s
 76357  1384 infeasible   77        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   519 4885s
 77046  1436   56.00000   85  151   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   519 4903s
 77680  1612 infeasible  111        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   519 4948s
 79106  1645 infeasible   85        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 4960s
 79699  1660 infeasible   82        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 4971s
 80278  1586 infeasible   62        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 4980s
 80854  1554   56.00000   68  124   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5007s
 81420  1551 infeasible   67        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5016s
 82081  1479   56.00000   89  141   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5026s
 82657  1603 infeasible   59        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   519 5035s
 83353  1607 infeasible   79        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5044s
 84049  1613 infeasible   69        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5053s
 84709  1565 infeasible   81        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5062s
 85333  1546 infeasible   69        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5072s
 85998  1552 infeasible   89        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5083s
 86658  1650   56.00000  104  139   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5091s
 87162  1655 infeasible   87        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5100s
 87801  1676 infeasible   75        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5109s
 88114  1676   56.00000   91  127   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5111s
 88442  1609   56.00000   86  134   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5146s
 89775  1525 infeasible   91        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5155s
 90351  1522   56.00000   81  141   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5166s
 90882  1518   56.00000   81  124   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5175s
 91464  1540 infeasible   90        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5184s
 92116  1525   56.00000   81  132   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5193s
 92673  1492 infeasible   72        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5203s
 93284  1581 infeasible   81        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5212s
 93969  1584 infeasible   89        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5221s
 94538  1508   56.00000   53  132   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5231s
 95024  1495   56.00000   72  134   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5240s
 95651  1472 infeasible   81        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5283s
 95912  1472 infeasible   84        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5362s
 95920  1448   56.00000   78  135   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5373s
 96484  1435 infeasible   70        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5383s
 97101  1453   56.00000   79  148   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5395s
 97649  1414   56.00000   73  138   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5405s
 98152  1376   56.00000   67  126   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5415s
 98644  1484   56.00000   68  141   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5427s
 99118  1468   56.00000   75  149   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5461s
 100424  1416 infeasible   85        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5471s
 100940  1426 infeasible   67        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5481s
 101520  1435   56.00000   83  124   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5491s
 102149  1388 infeasible   76        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5572s
 102558  1392   56.00000  102  140   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5585s
 103392  1444 infeasible   84        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5596s
 104180  1433 infeasible   77        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5606s
 104927  1478 infeasible   77        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5617s
 105734  1463   56.00000   83  154   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5627s
 106509  1458   56.00000   95  133   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5638s
 107180  1458   56.00000   71  129   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5647s
 107942  1416 infeasible   81        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   516 5657s
 108570  1442   56.00000   67  153   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5667s
 109216  1433   56.00000   99  154   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5718s
 109825  1435   56.00000   96  147   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5729s
 110528  1481 infeasible   77        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5740s
 111210  1453 infeasible   83        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5774s
 112332  1477   56.00000   94  125   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   517 5783s
 112948  1500   56.00000   85  131   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5793s
 113569  1560 infeasible  101        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5803s
 114235  1493 infeasible   86        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5812s
 114852  1498   56.00000   87  141   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5821s
 115485  1526   56.00000   85  153   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5831s
 116033  1491 infeasible  105        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5841s
 116606  1448   56.00000  105  146   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5851s
 117175  1417 infeasible   93        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   518 5861s
 117656  1435   56.00000   98  149   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   519 5871s
 118272  1449 infeasible  111        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   519 5880s
 118864  1445 infeasible   78        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   519 5889s
 119478  1422 infeasible   94        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   519 5899s
 120063  1358   56.00000  106  153   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   520 5908s
 120589  1527   56.00000   68  152   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   520 5918s
 121286  1577 infeasible   67        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   520 5928s
 121926  1603   56.00000   83  132   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   520 5969s
 122738  1582 infeasible   96        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   520 5982s
 123534  1579 infeasible   91        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   520 6067s
 123545  1577 infeasible   90        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   520 6086s
 124105  1592   56.00000  103  139   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   520 6102s
 124862  1596   56.00000   81  114   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   521 6115s
 125568  1559 infeasible   86        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   521 6129s
 126209  1545 infeasible   97        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   521 6141s
 126863  1586   56.00000   78  139   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   521 6157s
 127546  1599   56.00000   91  127   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   521 6174s
 128235  1668   56.00000   75  140   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   522 6188s
 128936  1675   56.00000  100  148   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   521 6201s
 129679  1672 infeasible   85        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   521 6213s
 130330  1664   56.00000   99  129   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   521 6224s
 130994  1637   56.00000   85  141   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   522 6236s
 131619  1645   56.00000   77  131   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   522 6248s
 132243  1602   56.00000   88  151   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   522 6286s
 133298  1589 infeasible  107        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   522 6299s
 133665  1698   56.00000   63  152   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   523 6314s
 134174  1716 infeasible  101        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   522 6331s
 134698  1676 infeasible  100        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   522 6348s
 135192  1685   56.00000   85  137   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   522 6383s
 135547  1700   56.00000   85  140   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   523 6405s
 136108  1687 infeasible  117        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   523 6425s
 136667  1655   56.00000   95  147   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   523 6446s
 137191  1629 infeasible  109        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   523 6465s
 138127  1587 infeasible   96        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   524 6483s
 138983  1539 infeasible  114        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   524 6496s
 139796  1556 infeasible   88        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   524 6509s
 140627  1693   56.00000   76  137   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   525 6524s
 141398  1676   56.00000   76  154   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   524 6540s
 142123  1687   56.00000   97  136   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   525 6557s
 142497  1687 infeasible   95        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   525 6560s
 142864  1740 infeasible  101        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   525 6577s
 143641  1705   56.00000   76  140   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   525 6656s
 144440  1654   56.00000   93  137   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   526 6685s
 146083  1610 infeasible   86        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   526 6707s
 146985  1542 infeasible  100        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   527 6725s
 147767  1626 infeasible   99        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   527 6742s
 148401  1731 infeasible   99        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   527 6759s
 149062  1740   56.00000  100  132   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   527 6776s
 149671  1776   56.00000   70  137   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   527 6792s
 150381  1813 infeasible   93        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   527 6810s
 151150  1761   56.00000   81  144   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   527 6828s
 151862  1918 infeasible   95        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   527 6841s
 152733  1896   56.00000  101  128   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   527 6855s
 153535  1814 infeasible   75        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   527 6867s
 154289  1823 infeasible   74        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   527 6880s
 154972  1820 infeasible  102        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   527 6968s
 154980  1820   56.00000   90  133   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   527 6970s
 154983  1787   56.00000   94  132   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   527 6986s
 155598  1755 infeasible   85        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   527 6999s
 156268  1721 infeasible   80        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   527 7011s
 156914  1750   56.00000   55  150   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   528 7024s
 157475  1763   56.00000   78  127   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   528 7037s
 158095  1736   56.00000   49  151   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   528 7073s
 159044  1732 infeasible   69        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   528 7134s
 159056  1777   56.00000   56  142   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   528 7149s
 159753  1802   56.00000   58  123   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   528 7161s
 160442  1843   56.00000   80  138   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   528 7175s
 161141  1826 infeasible   88        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   528 7187s
 161776  1956   56.00000   48  149   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   528 7199s
 162558  1965 infeasible   85        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   528 7208s
 163275  1984   56.00000   90  140   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   527 7219s
 163900  2139 infeasible   71        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   527 7231s
 164601  2194   56.00000   76  137   55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   527 7241s
 165360  2189 infeasible   81        55.00000   56.00000  1.82%   527 7252s
```

It appears to find a 55 solution rather quickly, but then is taking forever to find the optimal 56 solution. Eventually, after 3 and a half hours I got a solution:

```
Verifying solution...
status: 1, Optimal
objective: 56.0
{0: 1.0, 1117: 1.0, 11495: 1.0, 11960: 1.0, 13117: 1.0, 14379: 1.0, 14536: 1.0, 15015: 1.0, 1507: 1.0, 15172: 1.0, 15324: 1.0, 16147: 1.0, 16388: 1.0, 16729: 1.0, 17926: 1.0, 18102: 1.0, 18440: 1.0, 19084: 1.0, 20435: 1.0, 21488: 1.0, 2236: 1.0, 22658: 1.0, 22905: 1.0, 23115: 1.0, 23844: 1.0, 24149: 1.0, 24508: 1.0, 24989: 1.0, 25259: 1.0, 26122: 1.0, 26657: 1.0, 3065: 1.0, 31490: 1.0, 31741: 1.0, 31841: 1.0, 33370: 1.0, 34319: 1.0, 34381: 1.0, 34480: 1.0, 34566: 1.0, 36400: 1.0, 37111: 1.0, 37700: 1.0, 38281: 1.0, 38728: 1.0, 39329: 1.0, 39982: 1.0, 4631: 1.0, 5013: 1.0, 5234: 1.0, 5353: 1.0, 6010: 1.0, 8296: 1.0, 8441: 1.0, 8663: 1.0, 989: 1.0}
```

which translates to following correct permutations

```
length 56
{'04162735', '46310752', '23561407', '62135740', '02536174', '65374210', '43270516', '03157264', '65713402', '36401725', '16027543', '50143762', '30265147', '31457062', '25136074', '26750341', '10462375', '02431765', '07346521', '27604351', '64203715', '34716502', '27105634', '62045173', '74532601', '41703526', '71425603', '75342610', '72413065', '31647205', '47021635', '21756430', '10362547', '67013245', '43671250', '15624730', '45061372', '05246731', '32150476', '73206415', '01234567', '51263704', '52016743', '40325761', '61530427', '74102365', '35072146', '35461207', '76305412', '07645231', '46053127', '15406723', '47510632', '30152746', '65423071', '12405736'}
```

Comment: There is an automatic parameter-tuning tool in Gurobi. Running this would probably the first *cheap* approach. Besides that, i would try different params focusing on the information you already got: symmetry-exploitation (going for *aggressive* value here).

Comment: There is *a lot* of symmetry in your problem. One simple way to break it is to add an arbitrary but small (relative to the original objective function) cost per permutation. That way, the solver "prefers" some permutations over others and it helps it branch. Also, the problem is a pure set packing problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_packing so also check for stronger formulations or additional cuts on that well known problem.

Comment: Another approach might be telling Gurobi that your constraints (except the last one) are SOS1-constraints to enable SOS1-branching. Not sure if this is possible with pulp, but it is with `gurobipy`. Using `gurobipy`, you could then further use the `BestObjBound` parameter to stop the optimization as soon as a solution with objective value `upper_bound` has been found. In my experience, adding the objective bound as a constraint slows things down.